# Jenkins Offline cannot able to resolve Maven Dependencies

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am trying to Build a Maven Project from Jenkins.
My server is Offline, so no Internet access or no proxy settings.

Maven Project Build absolutely perfect from Jenkins if Internet is present.
 But same project fails to Build from Jenkins in absence of Internet. My repo is containing this plugin.

My Maven Home:/home/oracle/app/Trust/maven
My Jenkin Home:/home/oracle/.jenkins/
.m2 file Location:/home/oracle/.m2

Error: [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1: The repository system is offline but the artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.4.1 is not available in the local repository. -> [Help 1]